# The isomorphism with SO(2,1)

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

It is written in that [Paper](https://docdro.id/lDOOgLO) that

The commutator table for the Lie algebra is
$$
\begin{aligned}
& {\left[L_p, L_q\right]=(C-A) L_q ; \quad\left[L_p, L_r\right]=(A-C) L_r ;} \\
& {\left[L_q, L_r\right]=-L_p ;\left[\begin{array}{c}
L_p, L_s \\
q \\
r
\end{array}\right]=0 .}
\end{aligned}
$$
It is easy to show that this group is isomorphic to $\mathrm{SO}(2,1)$ when $A-C \neq 0$.

where, $A$ and $C$ are real numbers. Moreover, $$[L_{p},L_{s}]=[L_{q},L_{s}]=[L_{r},L_{s}]=0.$$

I know that

$$SO(2,1)=\{X\in \operatorname{Mat}_3(\mathbb{R}) \,|\, X^t\eta X=\eta, \det(X)=1\},$$ where $$\eta = \left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{array}\right ) .$$

But my question is how to prove that the Lie algebra of ${L_{p}, L_{q}, L_{r}}$ and the lie algebra of SO(2,1) are isomorphic?

Any help with that is appreciated.

Comment: @user10354138 Actually not, I need to prove the isomorphism between the two Lie algebras

Comment: Why not?  Just check the obvious Lie brackets...

Comment: @user10354138  Could you kindly provide me with additional elaboration, as my expertise lies somewhat outside the realm of Algebra and Lie groups?

Comment: Please do not use pictures of symbols for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched, and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @Shaun I edited my post

Comment: Thank you, @MathLover.